# Determine the truth value of ∀x(x^2≥x)

Tags: logic

Determine the truth value of

$$\forall x(x^2≥x)$$

and answer the following two questions

$1$. Does the domain consist of all real numbers?

$2$. Does the domain consist of all integers?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you tried a few cases?  What did you learn?

Comment: This is the second question you've posted here within an hour with nothing but the statement of the question. There's no effort on your part on both of them whatsoever. Sorry, but are you trying to get this community to do all your homework for you? That's not what this website is for.

Comment: This is not my questions my brother asked it and he tried so many times,I get help from your's and explain to him.

Comment: @zipirovich But as you can see in both questions and the corresponding answers, it works again and again (that the homework will be did by users) and I think this is absolutely annoying!

Answer (score 2):

(i) is False. Consider $x=\frac12$

(ii) is True. $x^2 < x$ only for $(0, 1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and $(0, 1) \cap \mathbb{Z} = \emptyset$

Comment: Did you mean $x^2\color{red}<x$?

Comment: Yeah, I did. Whoops

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I) Since the statement is a $\forall$-statement, it is sufficient to give one counterexample, to determine that this statement is false.

Since $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we can take $x=\frac12$. Then $\left(\frac12\right)^2=\frac14\geq\frac12$ is false.

II) For $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ this is true.

Proof:

Since $x^2\geq 0$ the statment is true for every negative integer, since then:

$x^2\geq 0 >x$.

For $x=0$ this is also obvioulsy true.

If $x>0$ then $x\geq 1$ and $x^2\geq x\Leftrightarrow x(x-1)\geq 0$ Which is true, since $x\geq 1\geq 0$ and $x-1\geq 0$. The product of positive numbers is positiv.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @IsharaPerera You are welcome.